# How to use GNU Parallel for small MPI jobs

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, multicore, gnu-parallel

I am currently trying to parallize several small mpi jobs on a cluster, i.e., each node on the cluster has 16 cores, each mpi job uses a maximum of 4 cores, thus I want to use GNU Parallel to parallize the 4 MPI jobs so that I can fully using the 16 cores by using 4x4 mpi jobs, I tried using the following 2 scripts:

par_mpi.pbs:

```
#!/bin/bash
NPROCS=16 #use 16 cores
NJOBS=4   #4 small mpi jobs

export WDIR=/work/user/smallmpi
parallel -j $NPROCS --slf $PBS_NODEFILE --workdir $WDIR ./cmd_mpi.sh ::: seq 1 $NJOBS
```

In cmd_mpi.sh, I defined the call to mpirun using 4 processes:

```
#!/bin/bash
WDIR=/work/fchen14/gpar/openmp
cd $WDIR
mpirun -np 4 ./mpi_lp #This is the mpi executable
```

However when I run this script 
    bash par_mpi.pbs 
and then monitor the CPU usage of all cores using the "top" command the press 1, it seems that only 4 CPUs are being used and the rest CPUs are idling:

```
top - 16:18:27 up 22 days,  4:24,  3 users,  load average: 9.36, 3.30, 2.07
Tasks: 688 total,  13 running, 675 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu0  :100.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu1  :100.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu2  :100.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu3  :100.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu4  :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.3%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.7%si,  0.0%st
Cpu5  :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu6  :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu7  :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu8  :  0.0%us,  0.3%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.7%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu9  :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu10 :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu11 :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu12 :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu13 :  0.3%us,  0.3%sy,  0.0%ni, 98.7%id,  0.7%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu14 :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu15 :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
```

Could anyone point out what is the problem with my procedure and if there is any fundamental understanding of GNU Parallel? Any suggestion is welcome.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you by any chance using Open MPI as the MPI implementation? Then add `--bind-to none` to the `mpirun` options.

Comment: Hi, Hristro, thanks for the comment, this does changed the CPU usage, however it seems only 12 Cpus are used instead of 16, even if I change the NPROCS=20 or larger, it seems GNU Parallel is not fully using all the available cores on the compute node?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how GNU parallel works. Just to clarify my previous comment: Under a wide set of conditions Open MPI binds by default each process to a specific core. Since the different MPI jobs know nothing about each other's existence, the library pins all jobs to the same set of cores. `--bind-to none` switches the binding off altogether.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for the reply, I have figured out the problem is that I need to put the back ticks around seq 1 10 so that it becomes `seq 1 10`, otherwise they are just 3 string combinations and that is the reason only 3x4 cores are used...